# Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have created a database "webportal".   and this is my "user" table script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateRegistered` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `skypeID` int(11)  DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and this one is "catalog" table script.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog`;
create table catalog(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `comment`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `inserDate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and when I try to execute the second script in the command line, I get this error...

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint.
 What is wrong with this code?

Comment: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; Try first to run this query to see is there something wrong with your Innodb engine. If you not get error, try to check if you already have foreign key named fk_catalog in other table, for me your table creation code works.

Comment: I found no errors in executing this command "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;"    and also no uses  fk_catalog foreign key anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using a old version of MySQL, you can add a `INDEX` clause to foreign key field to fix the problem:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog`;
create table `catalog`(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `comment`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `inserDate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catalog` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```